# How to correctly constructing 'Date' object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm running the next simple JS code in chrome console:

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d.__proto__);
console.log(d.getYear());
console.log(d.getMonth());
console.log(d.getDay());
```

And get the next strange output:

```
Invalid Date
115
6
5
```

Today is 10th July 2015. So why year, month and day are incorrect and why 'Invalid Date' for '__proto__'?

Comment: the `__proto__` is the stringification of the `date` constructor anyway. Which is not a date

Comment: Month is right because Date months goes from 0 to 11. `Jan =0, Feb=1, etc.`

Comment: Note that [*Date.prototype*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-properties-of-the-date-prototype-object) is a **plain Object**, it is not a Date instance. Writing it to the console calls [*Date.prototype.toString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tostring), and since it doesn't have a *time value*, *NaN* is used so the result is an invalid date. Nice easter egg. ;-)

Comment: What would you have expected `d.__proto__` to be?

Comment: @RobG: Notice they've changed that from [ES5 `Date.prototype`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.5). a) browsers will not yet have adopted this b) it was a rushed decision, one of the last before finalisation, and might have been a mistake. Looking for the first errate list and ES7 :-)

Comment: @Bergi—the OP might have been expecting *[object Object]* or similar.

Comment: @Bergi—identical result though (in this case). ;-)

Comment: @Bergi Was just curious why it's 'invalid'. Anyway thanks for all your explanations, I got it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all works like that because that's how the [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is meant to work.
None of the results you mention are incorrect.

[Year](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay):

> The `getYear()` method returns the year minus 1900;

So, for `2015`, it returns `2015 - 1900`, which is `115`. However, `getYear` is deprecated, use [`getFullYear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear) instead. (This *does* return `2015`)

[Month](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth):

> The `getMonth()` method returns the month in the specified date according to local time, as a zero-based value (where zero indicates the first month of the year).

So, January is `0`, February `1`, etc.

[Day](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay):

> The `getDay()` method returns the day of the week for the specified date according to local time, where `0` represents Sunday.

Basically the same story as months, they're zero-based.
If you want to get the day of the month intead, use **[`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate)**

And finally, the prototype, `__proto__` is really something you shouldn't touch. It's no more than a skeleton for a `Date` object, where the `Date` object will have it's proper values.

Comment: …also, OP was probably looking for `getDate` instead of `getDay`

Comment: @Bergi: I literally just added that while you commented :-)

Answer (score 2):

- The prototype itself is an invalid date. You should not use the prototype date, since it is every date and none. Each concrete date object overrides the fields with correct values.
- `getYear` gives you years since 1900. It is now 115th year since 1900, which is correct. `getFullYear` is arguably more useful.
- `getMonth` gives you the month with January being `0`. `6` means July. It, too, is correct.
- `getDay` gives you the day of week, with Sunday being `0`. `5` being Friday, this is correct as well. You might have wanted `getDate` instead.

Answer (score 0):

d.getFullYear(), month is 0 based and d.getDay() is Day-Of-Week, also 0=Sunday based and 5 is Friday. you want d.getDate().

Answer (score 0):

try `getDate()` and not `getDay()`, and `getFullYear()`.
As for the month, months start from 0 (jan is 0) so july is 6 and not 7.

Answer (score 0):

1) `getYear` is obsolete, use `getFullYear()` instead.

2) `getMonth` return values from 0-11, so instead of 7 (7-1) is displayed.

3) `getDay` returns value between 0-6

Answer (score -1):

Use `d.getFullYear()` instead of `d.getYear()`

```
var d = new Date();
console.log(d)
// Fri Jul 10 2015 12:40:09 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
console.log(d.getFullYear())
// 2015
console.log(d.getDay())
5 // 5 is the number of the day so it is correct as 0 represents Sunday
console.log(d.getDate())
// 10
```